# I am trying to only insert a new record into the database if that record doesn't already exist but it isn't working

Tags: java, sql, derby

Here is my code to check to see if a record already exists in the system before entering ther new record to the sql database.

```
            String sql = "INSERT INTO Stock (name, cost_price, selling_price, numberinstock, supplier) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?) "
                         + "Select name"
                         + " from Stock"
                         + "Where not exists (select * from Stock"
                         + "where name = "+NameTextField+")";
```

I am using Java, my sql and a derby database.
What I am trying to do is when a new item is entered into the system, the sql statement will check to see if that items is already in the system.

What is wrong with this sql statement

Comment: Do `INSERT INTO table (c1, c2, ...) SELECT ...` instead.

Comment: one of the reasons is the lack of space between "Stock" and 'where". When you ask a question, you should include all the relevant information, like any errors thrown (which by the way you should also read and try to understand before posting).

Comment: The only error that I get is an error saying there is an sql error.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do what you want using `insert . . . values`.  So use `insert . . . select` instead.  The code should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Stock(name, cost_price, selling_price, numberinstock, supplier) 
    Select ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
    from sysibm.sysdummy1
    Where not exists (select * from Stock where name = "+NameTextField+");
```

However, you should pass the second reference to name as a parameter, just like all the others:

```
INSERT INTO Stock(name, cost_price, selling_price, numberinstock, supplier) 
    Select ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
    from sysibm.sysdummy1
    Where not exists (select 1 from Stock where name = ?);
```

Comment: Just to add some value here, as Gordon Linoff said, you should always use parameters and not plain variables (e.g. Strings) as you make your application more prone to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

try using trigger

```
Create Trigger Modified_Order_Trigger
   On Orders
   After Update --as per youe need "insert, delete, update"
   AS

     Insert Into tablename (tables fileds)
       SELECT tablefileds
       FROM INSERTED
```